# Meta required login text is cramped

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

[image]

Surely the text shouldn't intrude on the border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this... and don't call me Shirley. :)

The change will be in tomorrow's deployment. It should look like:

[image]

Comment: That joke works much better when it's not written out.

Comment: @mmyers yes, yes it does...